# How to delete items from global array with a function in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How do I delete an item inside an array using a PHP function? I have tried the following but the array remains unaffected:

```
<?php

$fruits = ["banana", "apple", "kiwi", "pear"];

function deleteFromArray($arr) {
    unset($arr[0]);
    $arr = array_values( $arr );
}

deleteFromArray($fruits);

var_dump($fruits);
// returns the array without any changes...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are only unsetting the element of the array **inside** your function, but the variable outside of it isn't edited. Plus, you're not using a consistent variable inside of the function (where does `$rest`come from?).

You have to add a return inside your function, and then use your variable to call it :

```
<?php

$fruits = array("banana", "apple", "kiwi", "pear");

function deleteFromArray($arr) {
    unset($arr[0]);
    $arr = array_values( $arr ); // Not $rest
    return $arr;
}

$fruits = deleteFromArray($fruits);

var_dump($fruits); // returns ['apple', 'kiwi', 'pear']
```

Comment: `$rest` was my mistake, I meant to write `$arr` which I fixed in my question, anyway, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 4):

For this use pass by reference method.This method only use when you want to remove from original array.

```
$fruits = ["banana", "apple", "kiwi", "pear"];

function deleteFromArray(&$arr) {
    unset($arr[0]);
}

deleteFromArray($fruits);

print_r($fruits);
```

Comment: make sure to declare $rest first, because your code (as well as OP's) cause `Notice:  Undefined variable: rest in ..`

Comment: here no use of $rest so i remove it.This method only use when you want to remove from original array.

Comment: @samayo thanks for comment.in hurry i forgot that portion.

Comment: @BharatDangar but the `array_values` bit is important to reset the array keys, you shouldn't have removed it ;)

Comment: @roberto06 if array value is important your method is right.

Comment: @roberto06 and if aziz want to remove value from original array pass by refrence is correct.

Comment: @roberto06 here question is How to delete items from global array with a function in PHP.